# Python: how to make a struct.calcsize integer with a standard size 6?

Tags: python, binary, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

If I look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html at **section 7.3.2.2. Format Characters**, there are no Format letter for a Python Type Integer with standard size 6. I have tried '6p' or even '3H' but that doesn't work for instance in:

```
import struct
struct.calcsize('!6p')
```

Sorry if this sounds dumb... I am learning how to convert strings as packed binary data for the first time for a string message that has a length of 6 with integer as a value. So what is the proper letter format to get a standard size 6 for an integer?

**UPDATE**

My task is to convert the binary messages contained in [**`NASDAQ TotalVIEW-ITCH 5.0` specification document**, here](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalsupport/specifications/dataproducts/NQTVITCHspecification.pdf)

So for instance, if you look at **Section 4.1: System Event Message (Page 3)**, I would convert the message of type 'S' as follow:

```
class SystemEventMessage(Message): 
    type = 'S'
    description = "System Event Message"
    message_size = struct.calcsize("!HH6pc") + 1
def __init__(self, message):
    (self.locate,self.tracking,self.timestamp, self.code) = struct.unpack("!HH6pc", message[1:])

def pack(self):
    return struct.pack("!cHH6pc", self.type,self.locate,self.tracking, self.timestamp, self.code)
```

I get this error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 11
```

So I am assuming my error has to do with the '6p' since I can't find any integer with standard size 6.

**UPDATE 2**

So I use the below suggestion of using `6s` rather than `6p`, for the following message type "I" in the documentation **Section 4.6: Net Order Imbalance Indicator (NOII) Message**, I do:

```
class NoiiMessage(ITCH41MarketMessage):
    type = 'I'
    description = "NOII Message"
    message_size = struct.calcsize("!HH6sQQc8sIIIcc") + 1

    def __init__(self, message):
        (self.locate,self.tracking,self.timestamp, self.pairedShares, self.imbalance,
         self.imbalanceDirection, self.stock, self.farPrice, self.nearPrice,
         self.currentRefPrice, self.crossType, self.priceVariationbsindicator
         ) = struct.unpack("!HH6sQQc8sIIIcc", message[1:])

    def pack(self):
        return struct.pack("!cHH6sQQc8sIIIcc", self.type,self.locate,
                           self.tracking, self.timestamp,
                           self.pairedShares, self.imbalance,
                           self.imbalanceDirection, self.stock,
                           self.farPrice, self.nearPrice,
                           self.currentRefPrice, self.crossType,
                           self.priceVariationbsindicator)
```

I get this error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 49
```

Now that's strange since `!HH6sQQc8sIIIcc` is of length 49...

---

Everyone thank you for the help!

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.
Do you want to convert a string containing 6 digits to binary int, or you want to convert something into a 6-bit wide integers? Sorry, but, can you be a bit clearer? Adding your input(like) and describing expected output will help.

Comment: @Delen I updated my question... hopefully this is more clear

Comment: My friend and I were successful with the 4.1 version of this challenge.. but the 5.0 is causing me issue with integer of size 6... must be really easy but I don't know!

Comment: Yes, and I think that you've got the answer. If not, give us a shout. BTW, I just noticed that I made a mistake in my first comment. I meant 6-byte wide, not 6-bit ( XD ). And, the error you specified is raised when the input described by format string doesn't match the given values.

Comment: Just to make you feel better, I had same problem when trying to unpack 24-bit audio stream. The trick is padding and cutting off, and shifting bits to simulate int32, because int24, as you know is not defined in C, so not in struct as well. Same goes for your fictive int48.

Comment: @Dalen Let me try this out....sorry I was gone for a while! Thanks for all the help and will let you know if it works

Comment: Also, why would `6p` not work?

Comment: I added an update to my question about a new kind of error

Comment: The error means that the formating string describes the 49 bytes long input, but the actual input does not match the requirement. Did you try len(your_input). Just to be sure. 6p means that you have 6 consecutive p types, if I am not much mistaken, not that p is 6 bytes long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`NASDAQ TotalView-ITCH 5.0`**

```
[S0099123456Q]________________________________ wireline SEQ _____________
 | | |     ||
 | | |     |+---------------[[ Event Code   ]]
 | | |     +----------------[[ Timestamp ns ]]
 | | +----------------------[[ Tracking NUM ]]
 | +------------------------[[ Stock Locate ]]
 +--------------------------[[ Message Type ]]

Name           | Offset | Length | Value   | Notes
---------------|--------|--------|---------|-------------------------------------------------------------
Message Type   | 0      | 1      | “S”     | System Event Message.
Stock Locate   | 1      | 2      | Integer | == 0 Always
Tracking Number| 3      | 2      | Integer | NASDAQ OMX internal tracking number
Timestamp      | 5      | 6      | Integer | Nanoseconds since midnight.
Event Code     |11      | 1      | Alpha   | == { 0 | S | Q | M | E | C } See System Event Codes below.
```

In order to get `NASDAQ_Timestamp`,
grab 6-`uchar`-s using **`6B`** in the mask or **`char[]`** **`6s`**
and postprocess them into `int()` only if needed on the consumer side
which **defers latency** and **unblocks** destreaming engine wireline performance.

*<sub>+ also enjoy the Python 7.3.2.1. notes on BigEndian / network ordering once using "!" mask-prefix</sub>*

---

```
>>> struct.pack(   ">c2H6sc", "S", 0, 99, "123456", "Q" )
'S\x00\x00\x00c123456Q'

>>> struct.unpack( ">c2H6sc", "S\x00\x00\x00c123456Q" )
('S', 0, 99, '123456', 'Q')
  |   |   |        |    |
  |   |   |        |    +---------------[[ Event Code   ]]
  |   |   |        +--------------------[[ Timestamp ns ]]
  |   |   +-----------------------------[[ Tracking NUM ]]
  |   +---------------------------------[[ Stock Locate ]]
  +-------------------------------------[[ Message Type ]]
```

### Ad another question in **<kbd>UPDATE2</kbd>**

```
"!HH6sQQc8sIIIcc"                              _
 +||-||||-||||||----------------------------1 |_|_ "!"   a "Network"-Byte-order
  +|-||||-||||||----------------------------2 |_|   H as a 2 Byte unsigned short
   | |||| ||||||                            3 |_|_ 
   +-||||-||||||----------------------------4-|_|   H as a 2 Byte unsigned short                                
     |||| ||||||                            5 |_|_ 
     +|||-||||||----------------------------6-|_|  6s as a 6 Byte char[]
      ||| ||||||                            7 |_|  
      ||| ||||||                            8 |_|  
      ||| ||||||                            9 |_|  
      ||| ||||||                           10 |_|  
      ||| ||||||                            1 |_|_ 
      +||-||||||--------------------------- 2-|_|   Q as a 8 Byte unsigned long long
       || ||||||                            3 |_|  
       || ||||||                            4 |_|  
       || ||||||                            5 |_|  
       || ||||||                            6 |_|  
       || ||||||                            7 |_|  
       || ||||||                            8 |_|  
       || ||||||                            9 |_|_ 
       +|-||||||---------------------------20-|_|   Q as a 8 Byte unsigned long long
        | ||||||                            1 |_|  
        | ||||||                            2 |_|  
        | ||||||                            3 |_|  
        | ||||||                            4 |_|  
        | ||||||                            5 |_|  
        | ||||||                            6 |_|  
        | ||||||                            7 |_|_ 
        +-||||||----------------------------8-|_|_  c as a 1 Byte char
          +|||||----------------------------9-|_|  8s as a 8 Byte char[]
           |||||                           30 |_|  
           |||||                            1 |_|  
           |||||                            2 |_|  
           |||||                            3 |_|  
           |||||                            4 |_|  
           |||||                            5 |_|  
           |||||                            6 |_|_ 
           +||||----------------------------7-|_|   I as a 4 Byte unsigned int
            ||||                            8 |_|                                     
            ||||                            9 |_|                                     
            ||||                           40 |_|_ 
            +|||----------------------------1-|_|   I as a 4 Byte unsigned int
             |||                            2 |_|                             
             |||                            3 |_|                             
             |||                            4 |_|_ 
             +||----------------------------5-|_|   I as a 4 Byte unsigned int
              ||                            6 |_|                             
              ||                            7 |_|                             
              ||                            8 |_|_ 
              +|----------------------------9-|_|_  c as a 1 Byte char
               +---------------------------50-|_|_  c as a 1 Byte char
```

### Where:

```
Format  | C-type               | Python-type        | Standard size
========|======================|====================|===============
     x  | pad byte             | no value           |     
     c  | char                 | string of length 1 | 1 
     b  | signed char          | integer            | 1 
     B  | unsigned char        | integer            | 1 
     ?  | _Bool                | bool               | 1 
     h  | short                | integer            | 2 
     H  | unsigned short       | integer            | 2 
     i  | int                  | integer            | 4 
     I  | unsigned int         | integer            | 4 
     l  | long                 | integer            | 4 
     L  | unsigned long        | integer            | 4 
     q  | long long            | integer            | 8 
     Q  | unsigned long long   | integer            | 8 
     f  | float                | float              | 4 
     d  | double               | float              | 8 
     s  | char[]               | string             | 
     p  | char[]               | string             |  
     P  | void *               | integer            |
```

Comment: OK so if I use `6s`  I would only have to worry to transfer this into `int` if I want to have all the messages in a readable format in a csv file for instance. But to 6 strings or 6 integers that's weird... nanosecond since midnight is 13 digit long...

Comment: **Yes**, that is the very rationale - to defer conversion ( and put it as ad-hoc on-demand task ) so as to offload the tight-most real-time loop on wireline interface ( there is always plenty of time once post-process ( alike the `.CSV` export **`fileIO`** ) comes to happen, isn't it? A week-long log of **`DAX`** or **`XAUUSD`** stream (quotes) take about **many tens of seconds ( speak about an order of minute )** to get stored on disk, so plenty, plenty, plenty time to convert `hex2int()`.

Comment: The objection about **enumeration** of `NASDAQ_Timestamp`, kindly check properly the definitions in **`NASDAQ TotalView-ITCH 5.0, Section 4.0`** where items are introduced and explained. `NASDAQ_Timestamp == < 0, 2**( 6 * 8 ) - 1 >` which **covers more than 3.25 days**

Comment: I think this is it ... I must use `6s` BUT I added a new type of error I am getting in my question, do you mind to look at it see what may be the issue?

Comment: You might already know, that this should have been opened as another question and here you should make an http->link to the next issue with another decode-mask for a new message format - using an initial problem creeping via update1, update2, update3 ... is not compatible with StackOverflow Netiquette.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I should have opened a new question. But `HH6sQQc8sIIIcc` is exactly what I have... I have to do more digging.

Comment: Your collision seems hidden in [**`ITCH41MarketMessage`**] string handling. Check / test / post HEX-code for `ITCH41MarketMessage` to visually inspect what you pass to the **`.decode()`** before you let it crash, ok?

Answer (score 3):

`struct` is designed to handle C structures. That's why it only has stock C types.
A "6-byte integer" isn't a stock C type - you cannot write something like `struct s { int6 timestamp; }` to get a usable integer right away. That's why it doesn't work like this here, either.

So, how would you solve the problem in C? You would probably

- write `unsigned char ts_data[6];`
- copy the value to somewhere else
- pad it and
- interpret the result as integer

Now, all we have to do is express the same thing in Python:

```
>>> struct.pack('q',1324)
',\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'    #my arch is big-endian

>>> struct.unpack('q',',\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00')
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8

>>> struct.unpack('6s',',\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00')
(',\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00',)

>>> s=_[0]
>>> struct.unpack('q',s+'\x00'*2)    #check byte order to find out which side to pad from
(1324,)
```

Comment: As a side note, do watch byte order used in all conversions. I didn't specify it in the example because it's irrelevant to the matter at hand.